# Configure Dictionary with Unity

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

I'm trying to use the InjectionMethod with Unity 2.0 to register a generic Dictionary type but it keeps failing with the message:

> The type Dictionary`2 does not have a public method Add that takes...

```
container = new UnityContainer(); 

container.RegisterType<ContactRepository>();
container.RegisterType<ListContactsViewData> ("ListViewData", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

container.RegisterType<Dictionary<string, AbstractBaseData>> ("SessionDataDict", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager (),
    new InjectionMethod ("Add", new ResolvedParameter<ListContactsViewData> ("ListViewData")));
```

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: And why do you think you need to do this?

Comment: Could you please add the full error message and the signature of the method you want to inject.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `Dictionary.Add()` accepts two parameters. You need to provide key as well, like (note "key" arg):

```
new InjectionMethod("Add", "key", 
             new ResolvedParameter<ListContactsViewData>("ListViewData")));
```